# Horizontal nav bar centers, but links are vertical?

Tags: html, css, navbar

So basically my issue is my CSS centers the nav bar fine, but all the links are listed vertically in the horizontally centered bar.

It ends up looking like 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kboT.png
But I need those links to be horizontal.

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#baa">Description</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS

```
}
nav ul {
display:inline;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    float:left;
  display:inline-block;    
  padding:10px;
}
nav a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Refrigerator;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #778899;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
}

nav a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #FF3333;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked a bunch of times, what you are attempting to do is _center a horizontal list_. Here is [one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266618/how-do-i-center-floated-list-items).

Answer (score 0):

```css
        #nav ul {
            display:inline;
        }
        #nav li{
            display:inline-block;
        }
        #nav a{
            float:left;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:10px;
        }
        nav a:link, a:visited {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: Refrigerator;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: #778899;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 4px;
        }

        nav a:hover, a:active {
            background-color: #FF3333;
            color: black;
        }
```

```html
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#baa">Description</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS targets object with `class="nav"` and not `id="nav"`. Change `.` to `#` and it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to revisit lectures on CSS. You might also get interested with using flexbox like in the snippet below.

```css
nav a {
    font-family: Refrigerator;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #778899;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #FF3333;
    color: black;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#baa">Description</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```